# Error while exiting a while loop

Tags: shell

I am monitoring a log file through a shell script and once a string matches i want to exit. i am using a while statement to read the logs file. But the problem is my script never exits it prints the string which i expect but never exits. below is my piece of script

```
tail -fn0 $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out | \
while read line ; do
echo "$line" | grep "Starting ProtocolHandler" 
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
exit
fi 
done
```

Tried using `grep -q` but doesn't work out

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `grep -q`:

```
tail -fn0 $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out | grep -q "Starting ProtocolHandler"
```

It will exit immediately after 1st occurrence of string `"Starting ProtocolHandler"`

Comment: Yes correct 1st occurrence but when next newline comes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just wanting the line number?  What about grep -n?  Then you don't even need a script.

```
   -n, --line-number
          Prefix each line of output with the line number within its input file.
```

Couple that with -m to get it to exit after 1 match

```
   -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
          Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.  If the input is standard input from a regular file, and  NUM  matching  lines  are  output,  grep ensures  that  the standard input is positioned to just after the last matching line before exiting, regardless of the presence of trailing context lines.  This enables a calling process to resume a search.  When grep stops after NUM matching  lines,  it  outputs  any  trailing  context lines.  When the -c or --count option is also used, grep does not output a count greater than NUM.  When the -v or --invert-match option is also used, grep stops after outputting NUM non-matching lines.
```

So, you'd have something like

```
grep -n -m 1 "Starting ProtocolHandler" [filename]
```

If you want it to exit:

```
cat [filename] | grep -n -m 1 "Starting ProtocolHandler"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggetion as it a live log file i am using a while loop i tried your options it doesnt exit

Comment: You can pipe the output of the cat command to grep and that should give you a snapshot of the file when the command starts running.

Comment: I tried using grep -q it still doesn't exit .. i guess is there something to do with the tail command?